# RegEx for matching 3 alphabets and 1-2 digits

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to write a regular expression to find a match in a text having at least 100 characters. The match should be like this - Any sub string within a string that contains at least 3 alphabet to begin with, at least 1 digit following it and a maximum of 2 digits following the 3 letters.

Examples -

1. abcjkhklfd**pdn24**hjkk - In this case I want to extract pdn24
2. hjdksfk**pdf1**lkjk - In this case I want to extract pdf1
3. hjgjdks**pdg34**kjfs dhj khk678jkfh**lds1** - In this case I want both pdg34 and lds1

How do I write a regex for this ? The length of the starting letters for a match is always 3 and the digits length can be either 1 or 2 (not more not less)

This is what works if there are 2 digits after the 3 letter string.

```
[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{2}
```

But the length of the digits can vary between 1 and 2. How do I include the varying length in the regex?

Comment: The 100 characters should be checked ahead of time with a length function. To get all the ones you want just requires a findall type of function or a looping search function. `(?i)[a-z]{3}\d{1,2}`

Comment: "...at least 3 alphabet to begin with.." is a bit confuing. Judging from your examples I think you simply want to match every substring containing 3 letters followed by 1 or 2 digits, not followed by a digit.

Comment: Yes that’s right. Every 3 letter substring followed by 1 or 2 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression we wish to design is quite interesting. We can first add your original expression with a slight modification in a capturing group, then we should think of left and right boundaries around it. For instance, on the right we might want to use `\D`:

```
([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2})\D
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/SZbHPS/1)

We can surely define an exact restricted expression. However, this might just work.

---

Based on [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland)'s advice, we can also use this expression, which is much better:

```
\p{L}{3}\d{1,2}(?!\d)
```

[image]

#### Test

```
re = /([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2})\D/m
str = 'abcjkhklfdpdn24hjkk
hjdksfkpdf1lkjk
hjgjdkspdg34kjfs dhj khk678jkfhlds1 '

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

This script shows how the capturing group works:

```js
const regex = /([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2})\D/gm;
const str = `abcjkhklfdpdn24hjkk
hjdksfkpdf1lkjk
hjgjdkspdg34kjfs dhj khk678jkfhlds1 `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: `"abc123".match? /([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2})\D?/ #=> true`, but it should be false, as `'1'` or `'12'` is not to be followed by a digit. `\D?` has no effect. You can't drop the question mark because that would demand the string end with a non-digit, which is not a requirement. What you want is not what should follow the digits, but what should *not* follow the digits, namely, another digit. For that you need a negative look-ahead: `(?!\d)`. Also I don't see the point of the capture group. Try `"abcd12 efg345ghij21".scan /\p{L}{3}\d{1,2}(?!\d)/ #=> ["bcd12", "hij21"]`.

Answer (score 1):

At least 3 alphabets: `[a-zA-Z]{3,}`
1 or 2 digits (not more not less): `[0-9]{1,2}`

This gives us:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{3,}[0-9]{1,2}/
```

Comment: Ah, but what if this match is followed by _another_ digit? Should be a non-match.